# How to find row indices of large row matrix with n common elements in matlab?

Tags: c, matlab, amazon-web-services, matrix, time-complexity

I am trying to find pairs of rows which index a matrix with 2 common elements. I have a triangulation of a 3D object and want to filter the triangles by the angle of neighboring triangles. So, I have to find the triangles that share an edge. In order to do this, I must find the rows of the .tri file that have 2 common points.

I have 350ish .tri files each of them have about 7000x3 in dim. I have found this resource:
[MathWorks link](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/1853-search-nx3-array-row-wise-for-2-equal-elements/)
The accepted answer takes my mac air 15 mins, and Matt Figs answer takes about 8 mins per .tri file (I have 350!).

How can I complete this process? I have been told to try and code this part in C ( I have never used C). I also have considered just trying to install Matlab on a linux server and run it there ( I have never done that either). Any advice on how to either write a program in C or use an AWS server?

3D files located here: [3D files](http://tosca.cs.technion.ac.il/book/resources_data.html)
Here is the code I run:
(any suggestions to clean it up would also be appreciated)

```
addpath('/Users/len/Desktop/javaplex/nonrigid3d')
files1 = dir('/Users/len/Desktop/javaplex/nonrigid3d/*.tri');    
files2 = dir('/Users/len/Desktop/javaplex/nonrigid3d/*.vert');

time=cputime;
for k =1:length(files1)    
    X=load(files1(k).name);
    Pt=load(files2(k).name);

    %define a sparse matrix for holding angles between 2-simplices
    W=sparse(length(X),length(X));

    % Find common vertices: try with C
    Xs = sort(X,2);
    S = size(X,1);
    L = S*(S+1)/2;
    F = sparse(L,L);
    cnt = 0;
    Ntoshare = 2;
    for ii = 1:S
        for jj = ii+1:S
            cnt = cnt + 1;
            if sum(ismembc(Xs(ii,:),Xs(jj,:)))==Ntoshare
                F(jj,ii) = 1;
            end
        end

    end

[I,J] = find(F); % pairs of rows that have 2 common vertices.
cmn=[I,J];

% Calculate angle and store in sparse matrix. row and col reference triangles
for i=1:length(cmn)
    normal1=cross(Pt(X(cmn(i,1),1),:)-Pt(X(cmn(i,1),2),:) ,Pt(X(cmn(i,1),1),:)-Pt(X(cmn(i,1),3),:));

    normal2=cross(Pt(X(cmn(i,2),1),:)-Pt(X(cmn(i,2),2),:), Pt(X(cmn(i,2),1),:)-Pt(X(cmn(i,2),3),:));

    theta = acos((dot(normal1,normal2)/(norm(normal1)*norm(normal2))));

    W(cmn(i,1),cmn(i,2))=theta;
end   

% save W as a txt file as nameofimage.txt in current directory
[i,j,val]=find(W);
data_dump=[i,j,val];
l=files1(k).name;
filename = strrep(l, '.tri','.txt');
dlmwrite(filename, data_dump, 'delimiter',' ');
```

Comment: This starts to get smelly. You should really use the built-in triangulation class! Please elaborate more on the *filter the triangles by the angle* part of your question! I don't really get what it is you want to do after you found those small angles.

Comment: You should be able to replace quite some code with something like: `Tri = triangulation(X,Pt); Tri.edgeAttachments(Tri.edges)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are already lots of built-in methods for doing computations on triangle-meshes. Have a look at the [`triangulation`](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triangulation-class.html) class.
The following lines will compute the angles between non-boundary triangles as your code does.

```
%%// Generate triangulation data structure
Tri = triangulation(X, Pt);
%%// Find neighboring triangles
edgeAttachments = Tri.edgeAttachments(Tri.edges);
neighbors = cell2mat(edgeAttachments(cellfun(@numel, edgeAttachments)==2));
%%// Compute angles
normals1 = Tri.faceNormal(neighbors(:,1));
normals2 = Tri.faceNormal(neighbors(:,2));
angles = acos(dot(normals1, normals2, 2)); %// faceNormals are already normalized
%%// Generate the output you are looking for
data_dump = [neighbors, angles];
```

Comment: wow, yeah. I have 2012 and the the equivalent class "TriRep" doesnt boast the methods that the triangulation class does. e.g. neighbors. it only took 500 seconds to compute everything i was looking for. Thanks